# Creating build after every change in vuejs2

Tags: vuejs2

Is there any command or webpack task for creating build/dist of vuejs project.
Like right now we have to run command

```
npm run build
```

for creating build to deploy our app. I want something which will create dist folder  after every change in code (src folder)

PS: I want similar command like in angular2 `ng serve --prod` which will serve code along with dist folder.

Comment: Maybe [webpack watch mode](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/watch/) can help you.

Comment: do you have any specific command for the same ?

Comment: No, sorry. I didn't use that. I used `webpack-dev-server` (`webpack-dev-server --open --config webpack.dev.js`), but that is for development, not for production.